# Geocoder.class getFromLocation() 새주소 검색

Tags: google-api, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to get an address based on the long/lat

```
Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(context);
Iterator<Address> addresses = coder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1).iterator();
```

Mark's address in Korea since 2014, implemented in the name of the road. I would like to know the address translation is supported.

Currently, old address and new address is randomly generated.

Old address : 서울특별시 송파구 오금동 23
New address : 서울특별시 송파구 위례성대로22길